# Is there a pair of pants decomposition analogue for orbifolds?

Tags: gn.general-topology, surfaces, orbifolds

The pair of pants decomposition is a useful tool is surface theory. Is there an analogous decomposition for orbifolds?

Thanks

Comment: What would your "pair of pants" decomposition look like for a sphere with a collection of orbifold points? You would have such a decomposition if you also allow orbifold "caps" or "disks" that contain a single orbifold point.

Comment: For two dimensional orbifolds there are so-called small orbifolds that are completely analogous to pairs of pants, at least in terms of group theoretical JSJ theory. See section 5.1.3 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.05139.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to tell us what about the pair of pants decomposition you find particularly useful, but the obvious analogy is the Delaunay triangulation/tessellation with vertices at the singular points.

Comment: If there are no singular points?

Comment: @BenMcKay add a point and declare it singular.

Comment: @BenMcKay - If there are no singular points, then it is not an orbifold?